# Got empty array when send array from Axios to Laravel function

Tags: javascript, laravel, axios

I am trying to send multidimensional array from javascript to laravel function and save it in session

my JS array looking like this:

```
[
   1 => [
       2022-07-12 => [1, 2], [2, 3]
       2022-07-13 => [2, 1], [3, 3]
   ],
   2 => [
       2022-07-14 => [1, 2], [2, 3]
       2022-07-16 => [2, 1], [3, 3]
   ],
]
```

i have the array in javascript its correct, i am send it to laravel function with axios like that:

```
Axios.post('/meal-plans/set-weeks-meals', weeksMeals).then((response) => {
   console.log(response.data)
});
```

and in laravel function i want to save that array in session:

```
public function setWeeksMeals(Request $request)
{
   session()->put('weeks_meals', $request->weeksMeals);
   return response()->json(['status' => true, 'weeksMeals' => $request->weeksMeals], 200);
}
```

i got the in my response

```
{status: true, weeksMeals: null}
```

and this is my route

```
Route::post('set-weeks-meals', [Controllers\MealController::class, 'setWeeksMeals'])->name('meals.setWeeksMeals');
```

when i console.log(weeksMeals);

```
Array(2)
  1: Array(0)
    2022-07-12: Array(1)
      0: (2) ['1', '1']
      length: 1
      [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
    2022-07-13: Array(1)
      0: (2) ['2', '2']
      length: 1
      [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
    length: 0
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
    length: 2
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

and in laravel function dd($request->input());

```
array:2 [
  0 => null
  1 => []
]
```

and here how i generated the weeksMeals Array

```
let weeksMeals = [];

if (Array.isArray(weeksMeals[week])) {
    if (Array.isArray(weeksMeals[week][day])) {
        weeksMeals[week][day].push([meal.options[meal.selectedIndex].value, gram.options[gram.selectedIndex].value]);
    } else {
        weeksMeals[week][day] = [];
        weeksMeals[week][day].push([meal.options[meal.selectedIndex].value, gram.options[gram.selectedIndex].value]);
    }
} else {
    weeksMeals[week] = [];
    weeksMeals[week][day] = [];
    weeksMeals[week][day].push([meal.options[meal.selectedIndex].value, gram.options[gram.selectedIndex].value]);
}
```

can i know how to send this array to laravel function??

Comment: `$request->weeksMeals` is `null`. I suspect you're not sending it as `{'weeksMeals': [...] }`. Can you do a `console.log(weeksMeals)` and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72955310/edit) to include that output? Or, in your backend, `dd($request->input())`. I expect you have `{'1': [...], '2': [...]}` instead.

Comment: @TimLewis Thank for replay i edit the question and add ```console.log(weeksMeals)``` and ```dd($request->input())``` please check it

Comment: As I expected. If you want `$request->input('weeksMeals')` (or just `$request->weeksMeals`) to work, you need to pass it as: `Axios.post('/meal-plans/set-weeks-meals', {'weekMeals': weekMeals}).then(...)` 

Comment: @TimLewis I am sorry but its still not working after i changed to your code i have this ```$request->input()```  this is the result
```array:1 [
  "weeksMeals" => array:2 [
    0 => null
    1 => []
  ]
]``` i will add in the question how i generate the weeksMeals array please check it

Comment: what you think if i change the weeksMeals array to object

Comment: Yes, an `object` is required here. You'd still have to send it as `{'weeksMeals': weeksMeals}` if defined like that, which is fine. `$request->input('weeksMeals')` (or `$request->weeksMeals')` should work fine now, but it doesn't like your inner array indices (`1`, `2020-1-1`),  etc), but I'm not sure why...

Comment: @TimLewis Yeah bro i told you its working now after i changed the array to object
i have it in the function in the same structure.
can u add the answer to close the question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `$request->weeksMeals` to work, you need to send the data from your `Axios` call with `weeksMeals` as an `object` index:

```
Axios.post('/meal-plans/set-weeks-meals', {'weeksMeals': weeksMeals}).then((response) => {
   console.log(response.data)
});
```

Without that, you were receiving JSON like this:

```
{'0': [...], '1': [...]}
```

Which means that `$request->weeksMeals` is `null`. `$request->input('0')` and `$request->input('1')` would work, or just `$request->input()`. Once the change is made on the `Axios` side, the data being sent is:

```
{'weeksMeals': {'0' => [...], '1' => [...]}}
```

And `$request->weeksMeals` would work. I can't speak to the inner arrays not sending properly, that is likely fixed by defining `let weeksMeals = {}` instead of `let weeksMeals = []`, since `object`s accept non-numeric/sequential keys like `'1', '2', '2020-01-01'`, etc, while `array`s do not.